# why image grid not expand in angularjs ng-repeat but javascript working fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to expand image like google images search here is link of jsfiddle with javascript code it's working fine [javascript image expand][1]

```
  [1]: http://fiddle.jshell.net/XDaEk/638/
```

but i want to expand image using angularjs ng-repeat but it's not working, here is link of jsfiddle angularjs Code [angularjs image expand][2]

```
 [2]: http://jsfiddle.net/36BYs/56/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-repeat is not done making its elements before you call the imageexpander-logic. You have to wait for the dom-nodes of ng-repeat to be created before calling it.

```
function MainCtrl( $scope, $timeout ) {
    $scope.mydeom = [
                {image: 'http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Thumbnail-Grid-with-Expanding-Image-Preview-Using-jQuery/example/1.jpg',name:'Loren'},
                {image: 'http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Thumbnail-Grid-with-Expanding-Image-Preview-Using-jQuery/example/2.jpg',name:'Marry'}
            ];

    $timeout(function() {
        window.jQuery('.gallery-items').imagelistexpander({
            prefix: "gallery-"
        });
    })
}
```